# How to define the Texcoord Array when use MultiTexure

Tags: opengl-es

When I not use  MultiTexure. I use this function 'glTexCoordPointer'.
But I use glTexCoordPointer, it seams that I should use the function 'glMultiTexCoord2fARB'.
But 'glMultiTexCoord2fARB' this function is used only two number for U && V.
How can I use the Array instead of?

Is there any function ? or way to do this?

The program is running under opengl-es 1.0.

Comment: glMultiTexCoord2fARB is a immediate mode function, like glVertex. It's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use [glClientActiveTexture](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glClientActiveTexture.html)

```
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);    // <-- tex 0
glTexCoordPointer(...)
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);    // <-- tex 1
glTexCoordPointer(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but does glTexCoordPointer worked well in multitexture? I tried but there can not work. Is there any other GL Funnction instead of this function? I use Opengl-es 1.1. Thanks

Comment: I know this from 'normal' opengl, not from es version. Read the documentation and maybe that will help. From the docs: "glClientActiveTexture selects the vertex array client state parameters to be modified by glTexCoordPointer" so this should work... Do you bound the textures properly before rendering? give us some more code if you can...